# Module level generic types in Typescript

Tags: typescript, cypress

Not exactly sure how to word this, but I have created a set of custom commands for manipulating Redux stores in Cypress tests (https://github.com/svish/cypress-helper-redux/). The code works fine, but I'm lacking type safety for e.g. the store state.

I have the types ready in my application code, but I'm not sure how to "get them into" the dependency code in a smooth way because of how you add custom Cypress helper commands and, particularly, typesafety for them.

---

The commands are originally just regular functions, but to get them "into" the Cypress chain of available commands, you basically need to do:

**Have a function**

```
// cypress-helper-redux/src/redux.ts
import { Store, AnyAction } from 'redux';
import { STORE, ACTIONS } from './util';

export type Action = AnyAction;
export type ActionsCreators = any;
export type State = any;

export type Callback = (
  store: Store<State, Action>,
  actionCreators: ActionsCreators
) => void;

export default (callback: Callback): void => {
  const window = (cy as any).state('window');

  callback(window[STORE], window[ACTIONS]);
};
```

**Add the custom command to Cypress to make it available**

```
// cypress-helper-redux/src/index.ts

/// <reference path="./globals.ts"/>

import redux from './redux';

Cypress.Commands.add('redux', { prevSubject: false }, redux);
```

**Extend the Cypress chain typing to make the command "visible" and typesafe with Typescript**

```
// cypress-helper-redux/src/globals.ts
declare namespace Cypress {
  interface Chainable<Subject> {
    redux: typeof import('./redux').default;
  }
}
```

---

To then use this in a Cypress setup, you'd just have to add the following to the Cypress support file:

```
// cypress/support/index.ts
include 'cypress-helper-redux';
```

---

However, as you can see, when including this helper, there's no way to assign a type for these `State`, `Action` or `ActionCreators`, and since they're compile-time type-declarations, I don't think it's possible to do through a function of some sort either.

Basically I guess I want module-level generics, or how to call it. To do `import 'some-module';` and somehow *declare* that, wherever `X` and `Y` is used in that module, replace that with `MyX` and `MyY`, and have it "just work". In my particular case, I'd want to override `State`, `Action` or `ActionCreators`, with the types I have from the application specific store setup.

Is this possible somehow? There seems to be stuff one can do via `declare module` and such, but not quite getting how those work.